# MySQL UPDATE updating only the first row; SELECT with the same criteria returns many rows;

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
UPDATE ranking_position
SET    position = ranking_position.position - 1
WHERE  ( ranking_position.position > 3 )
AND    tournament_team_id IN ( SELECT id
                               FROM tournament_team team
                               WHERE team.category_id = 38 )
```

Which is supposed to "move up" the position of everyone team after the 3rd position that belongs to the category 38;

What is happening is that each time I run this query it updates only 1 row;

If I do the SELECT query with exactly the same criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ranking_position
WHERE  position > 3
AND    tournament_team_id IN ( SELECT id
                               FROM tournament_team team
                               WHERE  team.category_id = 38 )
```

I get the expected results (many rows).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: My crystal ball's broke

Comment: Almost certainly unrelated (I'm at a loss as to why you would be getting what you're getting), but decide if you're going to use the table names and / or aliases in your column specification or not.  You have a really odd mix there.

Comment: Please run both queries at once and show us the output. With the `SELECT` first, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try This .

```
UPDATE ranking_position
SET    position = ranking_position.position - 1
WHERE  ( ranking_position.position > 3 )  
FROM 
    ranking_position t 
    INNER JOIN tournament_team team 
                               ON  tournament_team_id IN ( SELECT id
                               FROM tournament_team team
                               WHERE team.category_id = 38 )
```